# Playing sounds in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add sound effects to my Visual C# program.  What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"ringout.wav");
sound.PlaySync();
```

Comment: I used sound.Play() instead so that program execution wouldn't pause while the sound is playing.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) to play a WAV from your .NET application.

Comment: wow beat me by 13 seconds, and you named the class long form, *snap*

Answer (score 4):

The [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class

Answer (score 0):

You can load a wav file into memory on startup let's say, and then play it on certain events.